# Controlling the updates in my Database

Tags: sql, sql-server, database, subquery

I came here today to see if someone could give me a suggestion to improve the way I update my database.

Here is the problem, I have one file that I store new scripts every time that I need to change something. For instance, let's say I need to add a new column in a table. I would add the following line in my file called `script1.sql`:

```
alter table CLIENTS 
add AGE integer
```

After doing that, I am going to send it to a client with an updated application, and ask him to run `script1.sql` on his database. That works just fine for me.

The problem shows up when this file starts to get bigger, and the client needs to receive the new updates.

The client would run the `script1.sql` file again, but now with more updates. He will get errors indicating that a column named `AGE` already exists in the database.

The biggest problem is when I change the version of my application. If I update my application from *Application1* to *Application2*, I also change the script from `script1.sql` to `script2.sql`.

Now, my client will need to run both to get to the correct version without conflicts. He will also get lots of errors, since almost everything from `script1.sql` was already processed in his database.

What I want is to eliminate the chance to face conflicts. This process has been working for me, but always causing some sort of trouble. Therefore, if anyone has any idea about how I could make it work better, please help me out.

Comment: You need something like [DbUp](https://dbup.github.io/) to break up your large script into many small scripts that can be executed and their execution protocolled, so that only new scripts are run the second and third time around

Answer (score 0):

Usually SQL provides something called `IF EXISTS` ( also `IF NOT EXISTS`) so eg you can write a statement such as:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS users ...
```

Which will only create the users table if it hasn't already been created.

There is usually a variant of this that can be added to all your statements (including updates such as renaming columns etc).

Then if the table has already been added (or column updated etc) then it won't try to run that SQL command again - which means you can run the same file over and over as many times as you like.

(Note: this is called idempotency)

You will need to google for the details on how to use `EXISTS` for sql-server